# Connect Nodejs app to MongoDB Via Azure

Tags: azure, node.js, mongodb

I have a nodejs application and my organization is using mongodb but via azure which I'm not too familiar with. I usually just go on the mongodb website and then go to the 'connect you application' option and copy the uri. I also wanted to know how I can access the mongo atlas interface through azure.

Comment: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/

Comment: Are you using Mongo Atlas on Azure, or Cosmos DB with the Monga API?

Comment: I believe its Mongo API and Cosmos DB. I'm not the administrator, so I don't know much.